# Payment Method Overwrite

Tags: magento2, overrides, payment-methods

I want to add new field in my payment method. I have added the field in phtml file in module but now I want to rewrite the file in my module. How can I achieve that??
Also let me know how to rewrite JS file?

Comment: You need to provide more details about this issue: what you have done so far (including code samples), and what exactly is not working.

Comment: i want add new field in custom payment method in magento2

Comment: i fooloow this but not done i did all smme

Comment: @tge may be you miss something or you need to provide more detail to this question be more specific about your issue like Alex mentioned in comment

Comment: i have module cryozonic_stripepayment payment method in my code folder ok now i want to add new field of zip in that payment form but i want this in my custom module i dont want make changes in stripe payemt module directly so how i override that html file in magento2

Comment: @tge: Can you please update more detail in your question like what did you try (where, how...)? I can't find anything relating to `cryozonic_stripepayment` in public. Is it a M2 premium extension?